# How to export Pandoc markdown to Worpress.com compatible PHP Markdown Extra?

Tags: html, markdown, pandoc, data-conversion, wordpress.com

I have markdown documents in Pandoc's standard `markdown` format, which i would like to publish on a free [wordpress.com](https://wordpress.com/) blog ("free" implies that i cannot install plugins or modify Wordpress PHP files).

Officially, wordpress.com supports the [PHP Markdown Extra](https://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra) variant that it converts into HTML, so theoretically i could just use Pandoc to convert my files into this `markdown_phpextra` format (which Pandoc does flawlessly).

However, as described in [this SO question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/107145) i noticed that my paragraphs appear wrong on the blog, because wordpress.com takes markdown-linebreaks literally when converting to HTML and does not reflow/rewrap paragraphs according to the "markdown_phpextra" spec.

For example, this `markdown_phpextra` text

```
This is a sentence.
This is a another sentence.
```

should become

```
<p>This is a sentence.
This is a another sentence.</p>
```

in HTML, but is actually converted by wordpress.com to

```
<p>This is a sentence.<br>
This is a another sentence.</p>
```

How can i convert my `markdown` files into some format that is compatible with wordpress.com?

- Is it possible to make Pandoc export every paragraph on a single line? This would immediately work around/solve my problem.
- Can i directly export with Pandoc into wordpress.com-syntax-highlight-compatible HTML? I have a lot of code snippets that aren't hightlighted when i use Pandoc to convert directly into HTML.

Comment: Can you add an example of the code that's not being highlighted? I don't know enough about wordpress, but others might be able to help.

Comment: When i use Pandoc to export to HTML and copy-paste it to wordpress.com, no codeblock is highlighted, because Pandoc creates incompatible HTML div tags: Pandoc creates ```<div class="sourceCode" id="cb7"><pre class="sourceCode Can Pandoc somehow set bash"><code class="sourceCode bash">...```, whereas wordpress.com expects `<div id="highlighter_592305" class="syntaxhighlighter  bash"...`. Is there some way to modify the HTML output or the class attributes that Pandoc creates?

Comment: Please add both, example input and expected output for code blocks, directly into your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pandoc has an option `wrap`:

> `--wrap=auto`|`none`|`preserve`
>
> Determine how text is wrapped in the output (the source
>       code, not the rendered version).  With `auto` (the default),
>       pandoc will attempt to wrap lines to the column width specified by
>       `--columns` (default 72).  With `none`, pandoc will not wrap
>       lines at all.  With `preserve`, pandoc will attempt to
>       preserve the wrapping from the source document (that is,
>       where there are nonsemantic newlines in the source, there
>       will be nonsemantic newlines in the output as well).
>       Automatic wrapping does not currently work in HTML output.

Thus calling pandoc with `--wrap=none` will put paragraphs in one line, as desired.