# How to escape angle brackets in wordpress.com compatible markdown within inline code

Tags: html, markdown, wordpress.com

I would like to display `/home/<user>/file` as inline code within a free wordpress.com blog, which supports [PHP Markdown Extra](https://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/). However when I write

```
A **text** mentioning a `/home/<user>/file` path
```

in markdown, the `<user>` part disappears from the generated HTML blog post. This seems to be wordpress.com specific, because it doesn't happen here on SO.
More specifically, it just happens when I write

- inline code outside of a table or
- a code block without a language annotation.

However, the following is ok (`<user>` appears in HTML):

- inline code within a table

```
| Item       | Note |
|:-----------|:-----|
| `<user>` | ok   |
```

- writing a code block

```
``html (with 3 backticks)
A **text** mentioning a `/home/<user>/file` path
``
```

with a language annotation.

I tried the usual escape variants like
`\<user\>` and `&lt;user&gt;`, but they appear wrongly/literally in HTML.

So, how do I write angle brackets within inline code in markdown for WordPress?

Comment: It works correctly in the [PHP Markdown Dingus](https://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/dingus/). Therefore, this must be a bug with Wordpress.

Comment: Yes, i think so, too. Wordpress.com doesn't seem to strictly follow the spec, but maybe someone knows a workaround. For [my other problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52915101/4936725) regarding wordpress's handling of  linebreaks in markdown paragraphs someone mentioned a satisfiable workaround.

Comment: See PHP Markdown's [configuration options](https://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/configuration/). Note that the behavior in your other question is likely caused by `hard_wrap = true` and the problem in this question is likely caused by `no_markup = true` (not the default on both cases). In the other situation, it was easy to work around by altering the input. However, there is no easy workaround here.

Comment: That said, I wonder why the `no_markup` setting is affecting inline code spans. If so, that would be a bug in PHP Markdown.